# retrieving values from a result set ruby sqllite

Tags: sql, ruby, sqlite, hash, resultset

I ran a query as follows:

```
 rs = conn.execute("SELECT * FROM fruits WHERE name = 'apple' AND type = 'sweet'" )
  puts "Results = #{rs.inspect}"
```

this gives me something like

```
 Results = [{"fruitId"=> 123, "name"=>"apple", "type"=>"sweet" }]
```

How do I get the fruitId out from this?

I tried this:

```
   puts "Retrieved fruitId = #{rs['fruitId'] }"
```

But that results in an error:
      [] no implicit conversion of string to integer

How can I get the fruitId out?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting back an array, but you want a hash to be able to use `rs['fruitId']`. That's what its complaining about.

Try doing this:

```
db = SQLite3::Database.open "test.db"
db.results_as_hash = true
```

Source:

http://zetcode.com/db/sqliteruby/queries/

http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Hash.html

Answer (score 1):

Its an `Array` of `Hashes`. You can access `fruitId` of the first item in the `Array` like this

```
Results[0]["fruitId"]
#=> 123
```